# Create Skiasharp path around element like a border in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I have a control in my Xamarin Forms application. Now I wish to build a custom progress bar around it, like a border countdown. But to start things off I need to know how to position this properly around my element (a viewrenderer) like a full border. I can successfully create a border object but the placing of the object is not right.

What I do is that I gather the X, Y, Width and Height from my element but when I add a breakpoint to this, it does not seem to give me any useful and accurate numbers. And it is shown when I deploy, the skiasharp object does not align as it should.

This is what I’m working with:

```
public class SvgPathCountdown : SKCanvasView
{

    public SvgPathCountdown()
    {
        this.InvalidateSurface();
    }

    private static void OnPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldVal, object newVal)
    {
        var svgPath = bindable as SvgPathCountdown;
        svgPath?.InvalidateSurface();
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty XValueProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(XValue), typeof(double), typeof(SvgPathCountdown), 10.0, propertyChanged: OnPropertyChanged);

    public double XValue
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(XValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(XValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty YValueProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(YValue), typeof(double), typeof(SvgPathCountdown), 10.0, propertyChanged: OnPropertyChanged);

    public double YValue
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(YValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(YValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty WidthValueProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(WidthValue), typeof(double), typeof(SvgPathCountdown), 10.0, propertyChanged: OnPropertyChanged);


    public double WidthValue
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(WidthValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(WidthValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty HeightValueProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(HeightValue), typeof(double), typeof(SvgPathCountdown), 10.0, propertyChanged: OnPropertyChanged);


    public double HeightValue
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(HeightValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeightValueProperty, value); }
    }


    protected override void OnPaintSurface(SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
    {

        SKImageInfo info = args.Info;
        SKSurface surface = args.Surface;
        SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;

        canvas.Clear();

        SKRect bounds;

        var rect = SKRect.Create((float)XValue, (float)YValue, (float)WidthValue, (float)HeightValue);


        var paint = new SKPaint
        {
            Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke,
            Color = SKColors.Blue,
            StrokeWidth = 10,
            StrokeCap = SKStrokeCap.Round,
            StrokeJoin = SKStrokeJoin.Round
        };

        // draw fill
        canvas.DrawRect(rect, paint);

        // change the brush (stroke with red)
        paint.Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke;
        paint.Color = SKColors.Red;

        // draw stroke
        canvas.DrawRect(rect, paint);

    }
```

And XAML:

```
<controls:CustomElement x:Name = "myControlElement" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.2, 0.85, 0.2" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" />

<controls:SvgPathCountdown x:Name = "svgPath" />
```

Code behind here i set the values:

```
 svgPath.XValue = myControlElement.X;
 svgPath.YValue = myControlElement.Y;
 svgPath.WidthValue = myControlElement.AnchorX;
 svgPath.HeightValue = myControlElement.HeightRequest;
```

How do i adjust my code so it matches the element when i do `SKRect.Create` with the set values in code behind? Maybe somehow i can get the svg path of a view control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple and straightforward solution would be to put the Skia element and your button into the same grid layout. Then give the other element a reasonable sized margin and draw your path in a way, that it covers the free space you get after the view has layouted:

```
<Grid AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.2, 0.85, 0.2" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
    <controls:SvgPathCountdown x:Name = "svgPath" />
    <controls:CustomElement x:Name = "myControlElement" Margin="5,5,5,5" />
</Grid>
```

Also make sure that you place your element AFTER the Skia Path element in order to prevent it from being overlayed by the skia element so that it remains clickable (if you use e.g. a button).

When drawing your path you should already have the width and height of the skia canvas in e.Info

Comment: Okay! And inside `SKRect.Create`, what values should i put?

Comment: If i added `var rect = SKRect.Create((float)this.X, (float)this.Y, (float)this.Width*2, (float)this.Height*2);` inside the create, then it aligns perfectly. Still confused why i need to double the height + width value however..

Comment: SKRect.Create(1,1, e.Info.Width-2, e.Info.Heigh -2) would result in a rectangle being drawn 1 unit away from the actual frame borders of the skia canvas.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to hear that this solved the issue.

Comment: Just for further information: The Height or Width values being used in xamarin are device independent units. That means that the resulting width will depend on your device's screen density, e.g. a width value of 300 in xamarin will result in a width of 150 actual units on a device with a retina screen (@2x).

Skia also uses its own unit system, so if you need to make some calculations alwas use the values stored in e.Info .